# Unable to send email via google smtp on centos VPS

Tags: java, email, tomcat, smtp

I am trying to send email via google SMTP.

The code is working fine in my local windows PC in tomcat.
But i got this error on my centos VPS

```
org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.googlemail.com:465
```

Here is code, please check it -

```
// Create the email message
HtmlEmail email = new HtmlEmail();

email.setHostName("smtp.googlemail.com");
email.setSmtpPort(465);
email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("username", "password"));
email.setSSLOnConnect(true);

email.addTo(e_mail, f_name+" "+l_name);
email.setFrom("me@gmail.com", "something.com - Account activation");
email.setSubject("something.com - Account activation email");

  // embed the image and get the content id
URL url = new URL("http://something.com/out.php/i6964_logo-email.gif");
String cid = email.embed(url, "BizzKiss logo");

  // set the html message
email.setHtmlMsg("<html><body>Something</body></html>");

  // set the alternative message
email.setTextMsg("Your email client does not support HTML messages");
email.setTLS(true);
  // send the email
email.send();

out.println("Email sent to "+e_mail+"<br/>Please check your email for activation message.Not found? Please check your spam folder.");



org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.googlemail.com:465
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1401)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1428)
    at org.apache.jsp.email_jsp._jspService(email_jsp.java:104)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 534-5.7.14  Please log in via your web browser and then try again.
534-5.7.14 Learn more at https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=787
534 5.7.14 54 qf7sm12328634pac.14 - gsmtp

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:826)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:761)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:685)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1391)
    ... 30 more
```

Please check the stacktrace and please tell me what is wrong

Comment: Is there a firewall blocking the request on your target VPS? What is the exception stacktrace look like?

Comment: How i can check firewall, there is no CP, only SSH
and where is stacktrace located in tomcat

Comment: Please check the stack trace above

Answer (score 16):

Even if the Gmail account credentials are correct, Google may still block authentication attempt, suspecting a robot mail sender. To fix it, make sure you are logged in using the same Gmail account in your browser, and then open the link below and step through the process of verification:

> https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

This will allow access to your Gmail account for about 10 minutes. Be sure to try your code within this time frame.

This trick helped me about half a year ago, hope nothing has been changed since then.

Comment: In my case, my script is on a VPS so I don't have a way to load any url with a browser. What I did: Changed my gmail pw. Gmail > Settings > Accounts. Then in Google Accounts they listed suspicious logins that were blocked by google (these were my script's attempted logins).  Then I clicked the option "Yes, that was me".  After that, my script worked (using the new pw).

Answer (score 9):

Whenever a script tries to login automatically, Gmail generally blocks the script. To enable login through script do this:

1. Go here
   https://security.google.com/settings/security/activity?hl=en&pli=1
2. In the list of signin, select the one which was blocked and contains the IP of your server.
3. Under Unusual activity click Change and Recognize the activity as yours.

If you do not have the activity in the list goto https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha and then try.

Both Tricks worked for me many times.

Answer (score 0):

Your host name must be **smtp.gmail.com** if you are using SMTP and port number can be either **465 or 587**. Your error log informs like your username or password is wrong so please ensure your account credentials and try again. Please have a look at this [google mail client](https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/1668960?hl=en&ref_topic=1669040) link.

Answer (score 0):

To enable send mail via gmail you must disable some security options in your gmail account: see https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255

Answer (score 0):

I got hung up on this... Make sure you set "Protocol" to SMTP+SSL.
Otherwise follow instructions here: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Setting+up+Google+Mail+and+Google+Talk+as+Notification+Servers