# Nodemailer/Gmail - What exactly is a refresh token and how do I get one?

Tags: node.js, email, gmail, token, nodemailer

I'm trying to do a simple contact form in a node app, using `nodemailer`. I want all the msg to be sent from a gmail account I made for this purpose, to my personnal mail.

on the client side, all I do is to get the name/mail/message of the customer and send it to the server. It works fine locally but fails to work when deployed (on heroku btw).

After a quick search, it seems I have to generate a `ClientId` and `ClientSecret` from Google Developers Console - which I did - but when it comes to generating a "refresh token" iI'm completely lost.

```
    var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP",{
        service:"Gmail",
        auth:{
            XOAuth2: {
                user:"myaccount@gmail.com",
                clientId:"",
                clientSecret:"",
                refreshToken:""
            }
        }
    });
```

**I am confused** : What exactly is a refresh token and how do I get one ?

Comment: See if helps - http://stackoverflow.com/a/35799085/4640499

Answer (score 117, accepted):

**Notes by this answer original's author:**

> So, I finally managed to figure it out. I'm surprised I couldn't find more ressources about that so for those who need to use `Gmail` with `Nodemailer`
>
> I found the answer here: http://masashi-k.blogspot.fr/2013/06/sending-mail-with-gmail-using-xoauth2.html
>
> Try creating a new User if you already had one and things ain't working fine. It was the case for me.
>
> I hope this will be useful to someone,
>
> Cheers

---

## Question 1: What exactly is a refresh token?

From documentation found [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#refresh-tokens):

> A refresh token provides your app continuous access to Google APIs while the user is not logged into your application.
>
> (...)
>
> **Considerations:**
>
> - Be sure to store the refresh token safely and permanently, because you can only obtain a refresh token the first time that you perform the code exchange flow.
> - There are limits on the number of refresh token that are issued—one limit per client/user combination, and another per user across all clients. If your application requests too many refresh tokens, it may run into these limits, in which case older refresh tokens stop working.

See also [Offline Access](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline) and [Using a refresh token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#refresh).

---

## Question 2: How do I get one?

### Step 1: Obtain OAuth 2.0 credentials at [Google Developers Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/)

As stated [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#getcredentials), you should:

1. Go to the [Google Developers Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/).
2. Select a project, or create a new one.
3. In the sidebar on the left, expand **APIs & auth**. Next, click **APIs**. Select the **Enabled APIs** link in the API section to see a list of all your enabled APIs. Make sure that the "Gmail API" is on the list of enabled APIs. If you have not enabled it, select the Gmail API from the list of APIs (under Google Apps APIs), then select the **Enable API** button for the API.
4. In the sidebar on the left, select **Credentials**.
5. If you haven't done so already, create your project's OAuth 2.0 credentials by clicking **Create new Client ID**, and providing the information needed to create the credentials.

[image: Image from the blog post linked above]

6. Look for the **Client ID** and **Client secret** in the table associated with each of your credentials.

[image: Image from the blogpost linked above]

---

> **PAY SPECIAL ATTENTION TO** specifying `https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground`
>   as a **Redirect URI** when you create a new User in the console.
>   Otherwise, you will have an error.

---

### Step 2: Obtain the refresh token at [Google OAuth2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground)

1. Go to the [Google Oauth2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground).
2. Click the **Gear Button** on the right-top. Set your **Client ID** and **Client Secret** obtained from the [Google Developers Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/), and select **Access token location** as **Authorization header w/ Bearer prefix**. Close this configuration overlay.

[image: Image from the blogpost above]

3. Set up the scopes. Use `https://mail.google.com/` as it's the one need by `nodemailer`. Then click the **Authorize APIs** button.

[image]

4. After OAuth2.0 authorization, exchange authorization code for tokens and **voilá! your refresh token is ready-to-use**

[image: Image from the blogpost specified above]

Comment: This was very helpful, but I was not able to actually get it working with the latest version of nodemailer (1.0) until I also followed the xoauth2 generator as specified in their [example](https://github.com/andris9/nodemailer-smtp-transport)

Comment: For people like me who read too quickly: `https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/` (note the final `/`) doesn't work! Only `https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground` works.

Comment: Thank you! Excellent work. I'm using Nodemailer version 4.0.1 and this worked like a charm. If you are merely in the testing stage of your app, Google requires you to join a group before it connects your app to the email address and allows use of https://mail.google.com. Otherwise, there is a review process to go through.

Comment: I wanted to add to my comment above that I'm running Nodemailer v4.0.1 in apps installed on both Cloud9 and Heroku without issue. The keys, as indicated, appear to be use of the most current version of Nodemailer, Node v6 or above, and valid Oauth credentials.

Comment: Just to confirm, is pasting your Client_ID and Client_Secret in the OAuth2.0 Playground secure? I guess it only goes to Google and they specify they don't log it (it was anyways generated by Google regardless in the first place). If this is for corporate use - is using Google OAuth2.0 still okay?

Comment: Is it possible to have the Step 1 and Step 2 in OAuth 2.0 Playground to be in my web app? So that the user can sign in by himself instead of having me do it for him?

Answer (score 7):

For those who have been looking around for a working example/code snippet, follow Radioreve's Answer until you are able to get the access token and refresh token. (Basically, go to the playground, make sure it asks for access for sending mail and mail.google.com, give permission, exchange authorization code for tokens)

Note that the `expires` time I entered was `new Date().getTime() + 2000` which was close to the expiration seconds seen on the playground. I am not sure if I had to enter access token and expiration time accurately as it seems to be refreshing the token automatically.

Use this sample code written in ECMAScript 6:

```
    const user_name     = 'something@gmail.com';
    const refresh_token = '';
    const access_token  = '';
    const client_id     = '';
    const client_secret = '';

    const email_to = 'receiver@gmail.com';

    const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

    let transporter = nodemailer
    .createTransport({
        service: 'Gmail',
        auth: {
            type: 'OAuth2',
            clientId: client_id,
            clientSecret: client_secret
        }
    });
    transporter.on('token', token => {
        console.log('A new access token was generated');
        console.log('User: %s', token.user);
        console.log('Access Token: %s', token.accessToken);
        console.log('Expires: %s', new Date(token.expires));
    });
    // setup e-mail data with unicode symbols
    let mailOptions = {
        from    : user_name, // sender address
        to      : email_to, // list of receivers
        subject : 'Hello ✔', // Subject line
        text    : 'Hello world ?', // plaintext body
        html    : '<b>Hello world ?</b>', // html body

        auth : {
            user         : user_name,
            refreshToken : refresh_token,
            accessToken  : access_token,
            expires      : 1494388182480
        }
    };

    // send mail with defined transport object
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
        if (error) {
            return console.log(error);
        }
        console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
    });
```

Comment: This seems to fired the new token every email sent, any reason for that?

Comment: @CaptRisky I didn't store the access token and its expiration date somewhere. Should I have stored it in a db?

Answer (score 0):

You can Simple use Google SMTP to send email. Use nodemailer with smtp.google.com and email and App password (not gmail password).

How to Get App Password.

1. Now you have to enable 2 Step Verification in Google ([How to Enable 2 Step Auth](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185839))
2. You need to generate App Specific Password. Goto [Google My Account > Security](https://myaccount.google.com/security)
3. Click on App Password > Select Other and you will get App Password
4. You can use normal smtp with email and App password.