# Getting error in Mail send Using Nodemailer

Tags: node.js, email, gmail-api, nodemailer

I create a project and follow all step written in answer of [Nodemailer/Gmail - What exactly is a refresh token and how do I get one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24098461/nodemailer-gmail-what-exactly-is-a-refresh-token-and-how-do-i-get-one) but i am error.

I use following code:

```
      var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP", {
      service: "Gmail",
      connectionTimeout : "7000",
      greetingTimeout : "7000",

      auth: {
        XOAuth2: { 
          user: "",
            clientId: "",
            clientSecret: "",
            refreshToken: ""
        }
      }
    });


    var mailOptions = {
        from: "", 
        to:usersEmailId,
        subject: 'subject', 
        html: 'string Of Html'
    }

        smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, response){
                                        if(error){
                                            console.log(error);
                                        }else{
                                            console.log("Message sent: " + response.message);
                                        }

                                        smtpTransport.close(); 
                                    });
```

Getting following error

```
{ [Error: Connection timeout] code: 'ETIMEDOUT', errno: 'ETIMEDOUT', stage: 'init' }
{ [Error: Connection timeout] code: 'ETIMEDOUT', errno: 'ETIMEDOUT', stage: 'init' }

{ [XOAUTH2Error: invalid_client] name: 'XOAUTH2Error', stage: 'auth' }
{ [XOAUTH2Error: invalid_client] name: 'XOAUTH2Error', stage: 'auth' }
```

and my second question is how to send attachment. I have only name of file and `url` of file.

Comment: Time to give a feedback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this because path wrong in nodemailer doc. this is issue in nodemailer use filepath this is working

```
attachments : [
    {   // file on disk as an attachment
        filename: 'name Of File',,
        filePath : 'url of file' // stream this file
    },
],

alternatives : [
    {   // file on disk as an attachment
        filename: 'name Of File',
        filePath : 'url of file' // stream this file
    },
],
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a wrapper module around *Nodemailer/nodemailer-smtp-transport/xoauth2*.

Take a look at this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/jonataswalker/75d10240ee9dbeb112b0) if helps:

```
// USAGE
// response is coming (in my case) from REDIS
var constants = {
  stmp_host: 'smtp-relay.gmail.com',
  user: resp.SUPORTE_MAIL,
  user_name: resp.SUPORTE_NAME,
  clientId: resp.OAUTH_CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: resp.OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET,
  refreshToken: resp.OAUTH_REFRESH_TOKEN
};

var Mailer = require('./my-mailer.js');
var mailer = new Mailer(constants);

mailer.createTransporter().then(function(){
  var send_info = {
    subject: 'A test!',
    html: 'some<br>formatted <strong>text</strong>',
    to_name: 'Some Name',
    to_email: 'some@gmail.com'
  };
  return mailer.getMailObject(send_info);
}).then(function(mail_obj){
  mailer.sendMail(mail_obj).then(function(info) {
    console.info('sent to: ', info);
    process.exit();
  }).catch(function(err) {
    console.info('error: ', err);
  });
});
```