# How to use Gmail as your IMAP server for Youtrack?

Tags: ssl, gmail, youtrack

I want to create a helpdesk project following this great tutorial : http://blog.jetbrains.com/youtrack/2014/02/using-youtrack-as-a-help-desk/

I want to set the parameters of my mailbox using a **Gmail** adress but I don't know how to **obtain a SSL key from Gmail**.
Without it, I have "Connection timed out" error. I know where to add the SSL key in Youtrack, but I need a file (JKS or PKCS12 format).

**My settings:**
Protocol:IMAPS
Host:imap.gmail.com
Port:993
Login:mylogin
Password:mypassword
Select SSL key: nothing
Connection timeout:60
Socket timeout:60

Please help :)

Answer (score 0):

Here how to obtain Gmail trusted root keys (from [Google PKI FAQ](http://pki.google.com/faq.html)):

> Google may decide to have its intermediate signed by another root at any point in time, so you should have an update mechanism in place for the trusted roots you ship with your product. If you are developing code intended to connect to a Google property, we recommend you include a wide set of trustworthy roots. We made an example available as a PEM file [here](http://pki.google.com/roots.pem).

PEM file provided can be manually converted to PKCS12 with, for instance, OpenSSL tool.

I suspect, however, that installing a cert won't solve the issue. "Select SSL key" likely stands for client (i.e. YouTrack) certificate, which is not required by Gmail. Please check the following:

1. If IMAP is enabled in your GMail account
2. [this recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18685936/unable-to-send-email-via-google-smtp-on-centos-vps/18687483#18687483) to make sure Gmail is not blocking new client application explicitly